# How to call a class of a jar from SSJS XPages

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-ssjs

In a project I want to use the javaxt library and call it from SSJS. So I donwloaded the jar file and placed in the the webcontent\web-inf\lib folder.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
importPackage(javaxt.io.Image);
var image=new javaxt.io.Image(strFileData)();
docTarget.replaceItemValue("GPS", image.getGPSCoordinate());
```

If I run the code I get the error message :

[0EB4:000D-0DCC] 2015-12-15 11:54:06   HTTP JVM: com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=23, col=9: Argument for 'importPackage' must be a package

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is javaxt.io.Image a Package?  What about changing it to javaxt.io?  Does that run?

Comment: as Rob wrote you need to import the package only not the class

Comment: @RobMason you should add that as an answer

Comment: yes that is correct importPackage(javaxt.io); works. I found out.

Comment: however I get an error message from var image=new javaxt.io.Image(strFileData)(); here is the error:HTTP JVM: com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=34, col=33: Cannot find java public constructor 'javaxt.io.Image()'

Comment: just read your code: you have extra () at the end of the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to expand on my previous comment.  The code `importPackage(javaxt.io.Image);` is importing a specific java class.  Changing this to `importPackage(javaxt.io);` will import the package and allow the code to run.